# View will appear is not firing when we dismiss notification settings overlay

Tags: ios, application-settings, viewwillappear, viewwilldisappear, viewcontroller-lifecyle

I have a view controller when a button clicked I'm taking the user to app settings.

```
 UIApplication.openApplicationSettings()
```

When I come back from appsettings to app then viewwillappear method is not firing.

or is there any other method that will let us know the appsettings is dismissed and user is seeing the screen right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using app lifecycle events (SceneDelegate/AppDelegate), not view controller lifecycle events (`viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear`, etc). [`sceneDidBecomeActive(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3197915-scenedidbecomeactive) should be fine for your purposes — for iOS 13+, you should be using `SceneDelegate` to listen to scene phases, like going to settings (becoming inactive) and then coming back (becoming active again).

```
/// SceneDelegate.swift
func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
    // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.

    /// your code here
}
```

---

If you want to listen to `sceneDidBecomeActive` directly in your view controller, try listening to the [`didActivateNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscene/3197920-didactivatenotification) notification.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( /// add observer
            self,
            selector: #selector(activated),
            name: UIScene.didActivateNotification,
            object: nil
        )
    }
    
    @objc func activated() {
        print("View controller is back now")
    }
}
```

Comment: May I use sceneDidBecomeActive Directly on viewcontroller or do I have to look for notification ?

Comment: @DCT yeah, you can use the `didActivateNotification` notification if you want. See my edit

Comment: Thanks it works.But how do I remove the observer ?

Comment: @DCT no need, it's automatic. But if you really want to, put it inside `deinit {}`.

Comment: Could you give example of removing it as well please ?

Comment: @DCT sure, `deinit { NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIScene.didActivateNotification, object: nil) }`. But as I said, this is optional. There's no difference whether you use this or not.

Comment: I'd like to keep one method in both activated()  and viewwillappear. Is it possible that activated and viewwillappear can get called sequentially ?

Comment: @DCT what do you mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: I mean if I keep a method invocation in both acivate and vewillappear.. I don't want both of them to be called together or one after another

Comment: @DCT so only call 1 or the other? Maybe set a flag, `var isLoaded = false` directly inside `ViewController`. Then in `viewDidAppear`, call the function if this is false, then set it to true. From then on, only the `activated` function (connected to SceneDelegate) will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to following appdelegate events

```
applicationDidBecomeActive
```

or

```
applicationWillEnterForeground
```

In ViewDidLoad use below code snippet

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationDidBecomeActive), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

and use below method

```
  @objc func applicationDidBecomeActive(notification: NSNotification) {
        updateTableUI()
    }
```

Remove observer

```
   deinit {
           NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
   }
```

Comment: Do I have to subscribe using notifications ?

Comment: Updated the answer now for your query

Comment: This works too. Could you give example of removing the notification please ?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: @RaviMan `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()` is old, in Swift 5 it's `NotificationCenter.default`